# using a row value as an identifier of values in the same column (Data wrangling)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working with an excel sheet that has unstructured data where the Account Names are in the same column as the Brand Names. I am seeking help to find a way to take the Account Name and move to be a corresponding value to every Brand that is under it. The pattern I find is there is an empty cell between every account and the other. I can't share the data as it is business sensitive, but here is a sample of what it would look like.

```
dictionary= {"Account/Brand": ["Account1", "Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4", np.nan, "Account 2", "Brand5", "Brand6", "Brand7"],
"value": ["", 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan,"", 5,6,7]}
df= pd.DataFrame(dictionary)



Account/Brand   value
0   Account1    
1   Brand1       1
2   Brand2       2
3   Brand3       3
4   Brand4       4
5   NaN         NaN
6   Account2    
7   Brand5      5
8   Brand6      6
9   Brand7      7
```

What I am looking for is:

```
    Brand   Account  value
0   Brand1  Account1    1
1   Brand2  Account1    2
2   Brand3  Account1    3
3   Brand4  Account1    4
4   Brand5  Account2    5
5   Brand6  Account2    6
6   Brand7  Account2    7
```

Comment: Is there any NaN value in between `6   Account2`  and  `7   Brand5`?

Comment: @sksoumik no the account and brands are following one another. only between One Account/Brand group and another is an empty row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just use `np.where` to create the account column and forward fill the nulls.  Then just select where the 'Account/Brand' column contains brand.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dictionary= {"Account/Brand": ["Account1", "Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4", np.nan, "Account2", "Brand5", "Brand6", "Brand7"],
"value": ["", 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan,"", 5,6,7]}

df= pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df['Account'] = np.where(df['Account/Brand'].str.startswith('Account'),
                         df['Account/Brand'], 
                         np.nan)

df['Account'] = df['Account'].ffill()
df = df.loc[df['Account/Brand'].str.startswith('Brand')]
df.rename(columns={'Account/Brand':'Brand'}, inplace=True)
df[['Brand','Account','value']]
```

Output

```
    Brand   Account value
1   Brand1  Account1    1
2   Brand2  Account1    2
3   Brand3  Account1    3
4   Brand4  Account1    4
7   Brand5  Account2    5
8   Brand6  Account2    6
9   Brand7  Account2    7
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! appreciate your help